# My Android app rotates even if screen rotation is disabled in the OS. How can I fix this?

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation, android-orientation, orientation-changes

I am developing an Android app that has full support for landscape mode. All of my activities have the following properties set in the manifest:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|locale|orientation"
android:screenOrientation="sensor"
```

However, if I disable rotation in the phone's Screen settings, my app still rotates when the phone is rotated. This kind of bothers me; it seems like the whole point of a system-level setting is moot if it can be overriden by an individual app. How can I fix this so it follows the system-level setting while still behaving properly if screen rotation is enabled on the phone?

Comment: What happens if you don't specify a value for screenOrientation?

Comment: Also maybe try android:screenOrientation="user"

Comment: Thank you, CaseyB. screenOrientation="user" fixes it. If you post this as an answer, I'll be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*You could try using*

> `android:screenOrientation="user"`

Answer (score 1):

You can try other way like this ,

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

apply these attributes after the activity name in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: No, that just locks it to the specified orientation no matter what. That's not what I want. I want it to listen to the sensor and change orientation, _unless_ the user has disabled screen rotation at the system level. Which should be what it does automatically (since it's a system-level setting), but that's not what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

you can add android:screenOrientation="user" and make sure there is no SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR in the java code or manifest.